# different routing to different OData controllers

Tags: odata, rest

I want to create several OData controllers that each has it's own route which is NOT the controller name.
I've tried using ODataRoutePrefix attribute but it I get an error:

> The path template 'People/Person' on the action 'Add' in controller
> 'Person' is not a valid OData path        template. Resource not found for
> the segment 'People'.

This is the controller:

```
  namespace MyODataWebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ODataRoutePrefix("People")]
    public class PersonController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {Id = "1234", FirstName = "Person1", LastName = "Last1", Age = 25},
            new Person {Id = "2345", FirstName = "Person2", LastName = "Last2", Age = 45},
            new Person {Id = "3456", FirstName = "Person3", LastName = "Last3", Age = 25}
        };

        [ODataRoute("Person")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Person> Get()
        {
            return _persons.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my WebApiConfig:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var r = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("ODataRoute", config);
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataPathHandler(), r);
    }

    public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
        {
            Namespace = "ODataTesting",
            ContainerName = "ODataTestingContainer"
        };

        builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person");
        builder.EntitySet<Animal>("Animal");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }

}
```

The person entity is pretty straight forward:

```
   public sealed class Person
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Any thoughts on what should I do in order to be able to call {my prefix}/odata/people/Person?
I'm using .Net framework 4.7 for now
Thanks!

Comment: is your intention for /people/person to return a single person or the whole lot? If it is all, why do you want the path /people/person, why not just /person or just /people

Comment: A better discussion, that we could take into chat, would be why you do not want to use the standard routes and naming conventions in the first place.

Comment: I've tried to keep the same routing conventions we have in our non-odata controllers, to do that I needed to use my own names and not necessarily the entity names. Thanks to your great answer below I see that's not how odata is designed, we'll have to think it over. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Register` method you have pretty said that you want to create the default routing convention, *but allow attributes to override the controller and end point names*, then map your `EdmModel` using those routes.

> The common misconception is that `CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting` allows you to define your own custom routes, all it is really doing though is allowing you to change how those default routes are mapped to your controllers.

This is sort of ambiguous in the documentation, the whole point of OData is to follow the standards, not to break them. The purpose of the `ODataRoutePrefix` is to allow you to map controllers in your code that do not follow the standard *OData* naming convention to the *standard* routes, that way you can still be compliant to the standards without having to refactor your entire code base for an existing API, or at least so you can manage your code and class names how you want to.

> Lets be clear: **OData Routes** are validated against and therefore *MUST* be mapped against the `EdmModel`.
> You cannot make *arbitrary* routes via attributes, the attributes on your controller class and methods simply tell the HTTP processing pipeline how to identify the correct methods to invoke.

## TL;DR

The following is a walkthrough starting from standard examples, scroll through to a final solution that matches your requirement, then read back across the rest to decide if you still want to implement your original route, I suspect that `/people/person` is a mistake, or that `/people` is supposed to return *all* and `/people/person(key)` should return just one...

## Correct Usage of OData Route Attributes

[OData v4 Routing Conventions are an OASIS standard, read the spec here.](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html)

So the standard route for your example, if you removed the `ODataRoutePrefix` *and* the `ODataRoute` attributes, would map this url to your `Get()` method:

```
/odata/Person
```

This resolves because your controller class name matches the expected convention `PersonController`.

This expectation is set by this line in `GetEdmModel()`:

```
builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person");
```

To be clear, the default convention is that a class that has a prefix "Person", a suffix "Controller" (so is therefore named `PersonController`) and inherits from `ODataController`

The same concept applies to `ODataRouteAttribute`. According to the specs, the expected *route* to return all the resources is `/Resource`, and the expected route for a single resource is `/Resource(key)`.

> For the end points, you *almost always* need to specify the `[ODataRoute]` for the standard CRUD endpoints, even on your conforming controllers, however if your do not have to provide the template if the rest of your method matches the expected conventions.

The *default* routing convention expects that on your controller will be an endpoint similar to this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return _persons.Single(x => x.Id == key);
}
```

Therefore the correct way to use `ODataRoutePrefixAttribute` is when your controller class does not have the *conventional* name, but you still want it to resolve into the OData standard convention, so the following would work, against the standard convention.

```
namespace MyODataWebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ODataRoutePrefix("Person")]
    public class UnconventionalControllerName : ODataController
    {
        private readonly List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {Id = "1234", FirstName = "Person1", LastName = "Last1", Age = 25},
            new Person {Id = "2345", FirstName = "Person2", LastName = "Last2", Age = 45},
            new Person {Id = "3456", FirstName = "Person3", LastName = "Last3", Age = 25}
        };

        [ODataRoute()]
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Person> ReturnThemAll()
        {
            return _persons.AsQueryable();
        }

        [ODataRoute("({theIdOfTheOneYouWant})")]
        [HttpGet]
        public Person JustOnePlease(int theIdOfTheOneYouWant)
        {
            return _persons.Single(x => x.Id == key);
        }
    }
}
```

## Work Around

Although I doubt this would work for your entire API, one option to satisfy your requirement is to map the whole *EdmModel* to the prefix `odata/people`.
*If you do this you would probably only specify *people* related entities in your EdmModel*

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var r = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("ODataRoute", config);
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata/people", GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataPathHandler(), r);
}
```

However you would still need to remove the `ODataRoutPrefixAttribute` and the "Person" template from the `ODataRouteAttribute`:

```
namespace MyODataWebApplication.Controllers
{
    // Remove this attribute, this controller already matches the convention
    //[ODataRoutePrefix("People")]
    public class PersonController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {Id = "1234", FirstName = "Person1", LastName = "Last1", Age = 25},
            new Person {Id = "2345", FirstName = "Person2", LastName = "Last2", Age = 45},
            new Person {Id = "3456", FirstName = "Person3", LastName = "Last3", Age = 25}
        };

        [ODataRoute()] // remove "Person" template
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Person> Get()
        {
            return _persons.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

## Custom Routes

You can of course still use standard `System.Web.Http` Routes and map those to your OData controllers to execute, `ODataController` inherits from `ApiController` afterall, but those routes will not be published or exposed via the *OData $metadata*

if you wanted to expose a custom collection of `People` from the `PersonController` via a url like this `/odata/Person/People` then that could be configured like this:

```
builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person")
       .EntityType.Collection.Function("People")
       .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Person>("Person");
```

then on your controll you could have:

```
// using conventional name, no need for [ODataRoute] 
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Person> People(ODataQueryOptions<Person> options)
{
    return _persons.AsQueryable();
}
```

### finally the originally required route!

No judgement... if you want `{my prefix}/odata/people` to map to your `PersonController` then you first need to change the configuration to *expect* this route, then your `ODataRoutePrefix` can be used, however it will not map the `/Person` route to the get method, to do that you would have to use the previous trick to declare a custom collection function, the result would look like this:

```
builder.EntitySet<Person>("People")
       .EntityType.Collection.Function("Person")
       .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Person>("People");
```

Controller:

```
namespace MyODataWebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ODataRoutePrefix("People")]
    public class PersonController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {Id = "1234", FirstName = "Person1", LastName = "Last1", Age = 25},
            new Person {Id = "2345", FirstName = "Person2", LastName = "Last2", Age = 45},
            new Person {Id = "3456", FirstName = "Person3", LastName = "Last3", Age = 25}
        };

        [ODataRoute("Person")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Person> Get()
        {
            return _persons.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

The difference is hard to spot, and is especially complicated in this example where the route, controller and class names all switch around between the english pluralisation conventions between *People*, *Person* and *Persons*. Its hard for instance for me to determine which one of these elements you have used incorrectly, so I went in based on the assumption that your data class names would be what you want.

Either way your expected URL is *unconventional* which by definition makes it hard to implement using the standard conventions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details response!! My intention was to keep the current routing conventions in our non-odata controllers.
I now see that it's too complicated so back for the drawing board for us to think about it again. Your answer explained everything prefect. Marked it as the solution, Thanks again :)

Comment: You can map other routes back to your OData controllers if you need to, but the reason to go to OData at all is usually because you want to make use of client side tools and techniques where you need to depend on the consistency of the conventions. I use url rewriting rules to map some OData v3 routes over to V4, not all mind you, just some common ones that some legacy apps still use. Maybe that is a better option for you

Comment: Great answer! This sentence cleared up a lot of confusion for me: "the correct way to use ODataRoutePrefixAttribute is when your controller class does not have the conventional name, but you still want it to resolve into the OData standard convention".